# Trying to get property of non - object Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

im still newbie, and trying to save data from REAXML file.

vendor for parsing REAXML from https://github.com/i4ucode/reaxml

Route:

```
Route::get('/admin/synctest', 'Admin\\AdminController@synctest');
```

**Model Property**

```
class Property extends Model 
{
   protected $table = 'properties';
   protected $primaryKey = 'id';
   protected $fillable = ['refID', 'propkind_id', 'other column'];
   public function Kind()
   {
      return Propkind::findOrfail($this->propkind_id)->name;
   }
   //other public function
}
```

**Model Propkind**

```
class Propkind extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'propkinds';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'name', 'slug'];
    public function Property(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Property');
    }
    //other public function
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function synctest()
{
    // get new class
    $processor = new \REA\XmlProcessor();
    $directories = Storage::disk('reaxml')->files();

    foreach ($directories as $zipFile) {
        //get XML file
        $files = file_get_contents(url('feed/' . $zipFile));
        //process the xml
        $properties = $processor->parseXmlString($files);
        //loop
        foreach ($properties as $property) {

            Property::updateOrCreate(

                ['refID' => $property->getRefID()],
                [
                    //other code
                    'propkind_id' => Propkind::where('name', $property->getCategoryNaskleng())->first()->id, ===> ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Trying to get property of non-object
                ]

            );
        }
    }
}
```

this piece of code `Propkind::where('name', $property->getCategoryNaskleng())->first()->id)` 
==>show data but trow

> ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object.

some kind of enlightenment, wisdom, very appreciate.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on first() returning a model.  It can return null if no model is found and that's likely your issue here.  You can't get an `id` property on null.

Comment: @Devon any wisdom still figuring out what should to do.

Comment: Always check if first returns null before relying on a property..

Comment: try `dd(Propkind::where('name', $property->getCategoryNaskleng())->first())` it return` #table: "propkinds" #attributes: array:3 [
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Villa"
    "slug" => "villa"
  ]`

Comment: You have a loop.... clearly one of the values of $properties doesn't return a model...  Like I said repeatedly.. check for null

Comment: @Devon thank you very much will check for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> clearly one of the values of $properties doesn't return a model

after several hours i found that **null** is the problem. 
thank you @Devon for insight. @simonecosci and @Leena Patel for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

the difference between `dd()` and `dump()` is that `dd()` stops the execution of the script (die), `dump()` shows a representation of the argument but it doesn't stop the script.
for this reason I guess that the error (notice) comes after the excution of this piece of code you have posted.

Comment: thank you for your comment. the error is in, that code that i posted. `Propkind::where('name', $property->getCategoryNaskleng())->first()->id`.